# Setting default Index for a Drop Down List in flex 4

Tags: web-services, drop-down-menu, flex4, gumbo

I have a drop down list that gets its data from a php web service method.This response is smthing like :

> array('id'=>integer,'name'=>'lin')

When the page loads, I want to set the selected index to "lin" initially. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to set selectedIndex property of dropdownlist control.

ex.

```
dwl.selectedIndex = 1; // "Index of "lin"
```

you should do this.

```
var iIndex:int;

for(var i:int = 0; i < arrResponse.length; i++)
{

       // if(Array(arrResponse[i])[1] == "lin")

       if(Array(arrResponse[i]).name == "lin") {
            iIndex = i;

       }

}

dwl.selectedIndex = iIndex;
```

Comment: But how is that gonna work ? I get the array from the database(its an array of arrays, I just wrote down the child array in my first post to make things clearer), and there's no way to determine its position from the webservice response... I mean to say... I may have some other name at selectIndex 1 and not necessarity "lin"

Comment: you can traverse response array in flex and find out the index and set as selectedindex.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I am looking for .. could you please elaborate ?